# how to change values of a dropdown on key press using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to change values of a "Focused" drop-down on keypress using JavaScript.

I need,

1. How I get a focused drop-down or how I can check whether the drop-down has focus.
2. How to change this drop-down values in key press like 1,2,3 etc. using JavaScript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to focus? `select` element?

Comment: [http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/listfill.html](http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/listfill.html) Refer this link. It will be helpful.....

Comment: Specifically what are you looking to achieve? Dropdowns have focus and change events you can tap into, but it sounds to me like you trying to implements a searchable dropdown list.

Comment: ya.. itz a good one.. but.... not according my requirement ..sorry...